# Python string formatting using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex ,I have a string in this format:

```
IhaveThisString = {WebhookName:webhook,RequestBody:somebody,RequestHeader:{emailCallBackUrl:https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz.logic.azure.com/workflows/efdbb900c/runs/00268387CU20/actions/HTTP_Webhook/repetitions/000000/run?api-version=2050-02-04&sp=%2Fruns%2F08sssssssssss0%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Frun%2C%2Fruns%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=eYmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhjIM,emailFileContent:hDQphc2xxxxxxxxxhpc2gsbWlzaHJhDQo=,emailFileName:456.csv,emailFrom:amitxxxx@gmail.com,emailSubject:Example,x-ms-workflow-id:6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbb900c,x-ms-workflow-version:08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx150,x-ms-workflow-name:runbook,x-ms-workflow-system-id:/locations/cxxxxx/scaleunits/xxxxx/workflows/6c14xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb900c,x-ms-workflow-run-id:08xxxxxxxxxxxxx0,x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id:c0889f0a-8ef9-5555-x111-77ldkfw98r34c54,x-ms-workflow-operation-name:HTTP_Webhook,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-scope-name:For_each,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-index:0,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-batch-index:0,x-ms-execution-location:xxxxxxxx,x-ms-workflow-subscription-id:hfhfh-d6s6d-d7d9s-7ASassASasas4,x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name:rg_poc,x-ms-tracking-id:c3-5xxxx-xxxxx-asdsd-2xxxx21,x-ms-correlation-id:c3xxxxx-5xxxx-4xxxx-xxxxx-25xxxxx,x-ms-client-request-id:cxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxxx-axxx-2sssssz21,x-ms-client-tracking-id:08wwsswsCU16,x-ms-action-tracking-id:b1sdsd6-85sdsd-4fsdsd-sddc-988888888891,x-ms-zone-redundancy:optional,x-ms-activity-vector:AB.0L.OU.23,Connection:Keep-Alive,Accept-Encoding:gzip,Accept-Language:en,Host:xxxxxxxxxxx0418b.webhook.eus.azure-automation.net,User-Agent:azure-logic-apps/1.0}}"
```

I need to use json.load to convert above into json_object.

```
json_object = json.loads(IhaveThisString)
```

But problem is single quote are missing in my string before and after colon.

I need to reformat the string like this:

```
{'WebhookName':'webhook','RequestBody':'somebody','RequestHeader':{'emailCallBackUrl':'https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz.logic.azure.com/workflows/efdbb900c/runs/00268387CU20/actions/HTTP_Webhook/repetitions/000000/run?api-version=2050-02-04&sp=%2Fruns%2F08sssssssssss0%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Frun%2C%2Fruns%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=eYmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhjIM','emailFileContent':'hDQphc2xxxxxxxxxhpc2gsbWlzaHJhDQo=','emailFileName':'456.csv','emailFrom':'amitxxxx@gmail.com','emailSubject':'Example','x-ms-workflow-id':'6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbb900c','x-ms-workflow-version':'08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx150','x-ms-workflow-name':'runbook','x-ms-workflow-system-id':'/locations/cxxxxx/scaleunits/xxxxx/workflows/6c14xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb900c','x-ms-workflow-run-id':'08xxxxxxxxxxxxx0','x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id':'c0889f0a-8ef9-5555-x111-77ldkfw98r34c54','x-ms-workflow-operation-name':'HTTP_Webhook','x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-scope-name':'For_each','x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-index':'0','x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-batch-index':'0','x-ms-execution-location':'xxxxxxxx','x-ms-workflow-subscription-id':'hfhfh-d6s6d-d7d9s-7ASassASasas4','x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name':'rg_poc','x-ms-tracking-id':'c3-5xxxx-xxxxx-asdsd-2xxxx21','x-ms-correlation-id':'c3xxxxx-5xxxx-4xxxx-xxxxx-25xxxxx','x-ms-client-request-id':'cxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxxx-axxx-2sssssz21','x-ms-client-tracking-id':'08wwsswsCU16','x-ms-action-tracking-id':'b1sdsd6-85sdsd-4fsdsd-sddc-988888888891','x-ms-zone-redundancy':'optional','x-ms-activity-vector':'AB.0L.OU.23','Connection':'Keep-Alive','Accept-Encoding':'gzip','Accept-Language':'en','Host':'xxxxxxxxxxx0418b.webhook.eus.azure-automation.net','User-Agent':'azure-logic-apps/1.0'}}"
```

Please let me know how to use re in python to achieve the same.

note: given data have URL like `emailCallBackUrl:https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz` which should get converted to like `'emailCallBackUrl':'https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz'`

Comment: That's going to be annoying because one of the values also has `:` in the middle, which should not be a separator

Comment: Single quotes still don’t make it valid JSON!? Why do you have this not-a-JSON to begin with? If it’s not JSON, why try to make it JSON before parsing it? Parse it on its own terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun one to solve, thanks for the clear explanation and example input!

The basic approach is to find sequences of characters that are not delimiter symbols (`:`, `{`, `}`, `,`):

```
[^{:},]+
```

However this doesn't quite work as the `https:` gets split up from the rest of the URL (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/aPKyea/1)).

This can be resolved by allowing for an optional `https:` inside the capturing group:

```
((?:https:)?[^{:},]+)
```

See the regex working [here](https://regex101.com/r/DYwWFS/1). Of course you could add any other exceptions you need to in this way (e.g. `((?:https:|http:)?[^{:},]+)` to also capture `http:`.

Full Python code:

```
IhaveThisString = "{WebhookName:webhook,RequestBody:somebody,RequestHeader:{emailCallBackUrl:https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz.logic.azure.com/workflows/efdbb900c/runs/00268387CU20/actions/HTTP_Webhook/repetitions/000000/run?api-version=2050-02-04&sp=%2Fruns%2F08sssssssssss0%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Frun%2C%2Fruns%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=eYmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhjIM,emailFileContent:hDQphc2xxxxxxxxxhpc2gsbWlzaHJhDQo=,emailFileName:456.csv,emailFrom:amitxxxx@gmail.com,emailSubject:Example,x-ms-workflow-id:6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbb900c,x-ms-workflow-version:08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx150,x-ms-workflow-name:runbook,x-ms-workflow-system-id:/locations/cxxxxx/scaleunits/xxxxx/workflows/6c14xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb900c,x-ms-workflow-run-id:08xxxxxxxxxxxxx0,x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id:c0889f0a-8ef9-5555-x111-77ldkfw98r34c54,x-ms-workflow-operation-name:HTTP_Webhook,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-scope-name:For_each,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-index:0,x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-batch-index:0,x-ms-execution-location:xxxxxxxx,x-ms-workflow-subscription-id:hfhfh-d6s6d-d7d9s-7ASassASasas4,x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name:rg_poc,x-ms-tracking-id:c3-5xxxx-xxxxx-asdsd-2xxxx21,x-ms-correlation-id:c3xxxxx-5xxxx-4xxxx-xxxxx-25xxxxx,x-ms-client-request-id:cxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxxx-axxx-2sssssz21,x-ms-client-tracking-id:08wwsswsCU16,x-ms-action-tracking-id:b1sdsd6-85sdsd-4fsdsd-sddc-988888888891,x-ms-zone-redundancy:optional,x-ms-activity-vector:AB.0L.OU.23,Connection:Keep-Alive,Accept-Encoding:gzip,Accept-Language:en,Host:xxxxxxxxxxx0418b.webhook.eus.azure-automation.net,User-Agent:azure-logic-apps/1.0}}"

import re
import json
import pprint

with_quotes = re.sub(r'((?:https:)?[^{:},]+)', r'"\1"', IhaveThisString)
my_json = json.loads(with_quotes)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=4)
pp.pprint(my_json)
```

Output:

```
{'RequestBody': 'somebody',
'RequestHeader': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                'Accept-Language': 'en',
                'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                'Host': 'xxxxxxxxxxx0418b.webhook.eus.azure-automation.net',
                'User-Agent': 'azure-logic-apps/1.0',
                'emailCallBackUrl': 'https://yyyy-xx.zzzzz.logic.azure.com/workflows/efdbb900c/runs/00268387CU20/actions/HTTP_Webhook/repetitions/000000/run?api-version=2050-02-04&sp=%2Fruns%2F08sssssssssss0%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Frun%2C%2Fruns%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20%2Factions%2FHTTP_Webhook%2Frepetitions%2F000000%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=eYmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhjIM',
                'emailFileContent': 'hDQphc2xxxxxxxxxhpc2gsbWlzaHJhDQo=',
                'emailFileName': '456.csv',
                'emailFrom': 'amitxxxx@gmail.com',
                'emailSubject': 'Example',
                'x-ms-action-tracking-id': 'b1sdsd6-85sdsd-4fsdsd-sddc-988888888891',
                'x-ms-activity-vector': 'AB.0L.OU.23',
                'x-ms-client-request-id': 'cxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxxx-axxx-2sssssz21',
                'x-ms-client-tracking-id': '08wwsswsCU16',
                'x-ms-correlation-id': 'c3xxxxx-5xxxx-4xxxx-xxxxx-25xxxxx',
                'x-ms-execution-location': 'xxxxxxxx',
                'x-ms-tracking-id': 'c3-5xxxx-xxxxx-asdsd-2xxxx21',
                'x-ms-workflow-id': '6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbb900c',
                'x-ms-workflow-name': 'runbook',
                'x-ms-workflow-operation-name': 'HTTP_Webhook',
                'x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-batch-index': '0',
                'x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-index': '0',
                'x-ms-workflow-repeatitem-scope-name': 'For_each',
                'x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name': 'rg_poc',
                'x-ms-workflow-run-id': '08xxxxxxxxxxxxx0',
                'x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id': 'c0889f0a-8ef9-5555-x111-77ldkfw98r34c54',
                'x-ms-workflow-subscription-id': 'hfhfh-d6s6d-d7d9s-7ASassASasas4',
                'x-ms-workflow-system-id': '/locations/cxxxxx/scaleunits/xxxxx/workflows/6c14xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb900c',
                'x-ms-workflow-version': '08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx150',
                'x-ms-zone-redundancy': 'optional'},
'WebhookName': 'webhook'}
```

Comment: you made my day. Your solution works perfectly fine and thanks for explaining it so well.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be annoying and brittle and unreliable, because some of the values also have `:` (or potentially some of the other special characters) as part of the value; in the example, the URL `https://...` has a colon but it shouldn't be taken as a JSON colon...

This will be even worse with fields like `emailSubject` which can probably contain absolutely anything.

The example you gave can work with something like this:

```
with_quotes = re.sub(r'[{}:,]+', r'"\g<0>"', IhaveThisString)

# fix up URLs broken by the quoting
with_quotes = re.sub('(https?)":"//', r'\g<1>://', with_quotes)

assert with_quotes[0] == with_quotes[-1] == '"'

print(with_quotes)

json_object = json.loads(with_quotes[1:-1])

pprint.pprint(json_object)
```

However, it's not a great solution, because punctuation in the `emailSubject` field will throw it off.

Ideally, try fixing the system sending you this data.

Otherwise, you may end up having to parse this by hand, without relying on `json.loads`, picking out the information you need from the data you have.